# Cordova store small pice of information inside the application

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I want to store some value like "Username" insight my application. When application kills from background that value remains store. just like in iOS NSUserDefaults. I know the another way to achieve that thing using SQLight but I don't want to use this. I got one link [please refer this](https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences/blob/master/README.md)  . But I can't get the clear idea. please help me. and write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LocalStorage.

```
   set an item : localStorage.setItem("key","value");
   get an item : var x = localStorage.getItem("key");
   clear all :localStorage.clear();
   remove an key : localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

But if you erase the NSUserdefault or SharedPreference from native code, automatically LocalStorage values will be cleared.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html